# How to "hide" the picture by the quantmod in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quantmod

I use RStudio 0.99.903.

I want to draw a picture by the quantmod in rmarkdown. Here below is the code:

```
{r, echo=FALSE}   
getSymbols("AAPL")   
chartSeries(AAPL)   
addADX()
```

I only want the final picture to be show in the document. But there will be two of them, one without ADX, one with ADX.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be a possible solution:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
    library(quantmod)
    getSymbols("AAPL")   
    chartSeries(AAPL)
```
```{r, echo = FALSE}
    addADX()  
```
````

This means, that the first chunk is executed but you don't see the result (`include = FALSE`)  and the result second one appears in your document, but not the function call (`echo = FALSE`).